# How to get Bluetooth LE characteristic value from packed byte array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluetooth-lowenergy

Using the [examples](https://github.com/noble/noble/wiki/Getting-started) in the [Noble-Master Node package](https://github.com/noble/noble), I've got as far as finding the top-level characteristic I need from the TacX Vortex Bluetooth Le bike trainer I'm using. However, I cannot figure how to get the Cumulative Wheel Revolutions from the packed byte array. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45677032/how-do-you-get-data-from-a-bluetooth-le-device) for Android using native Bluetooth functionality says the value is 32 bit, and the offset is 4, but `data.readUInt32LE(4)` throws an `index out of range` error. When examined using `data.length`, `data` appears to be an array, but mystifyingly seems to alternate between containing 11 values or seven values. When read one by one using `data[n]`, none of the values found correlate with what the back wheel of the bike is doing (the manufacturer's test android app shows I should be getting ~100rpm at full tilt). Nor do they when I change the offset in `data.readUInt32LE(n)` for 0 to 3. My question is, how do I extract Cumulative Wheel Revs from the CSC Measurement Characteristic using Javascript?

```js
var noble = require('./index');

noble.on('stateChange', function(state) {
  if (state === 'poweredOn') {
    noble.startScanning();
  } else {
    noble.stopScanning();
  }
});

noble.on('discover', function(peripheral) {

  peripheral.connect(function(error) {

    console.log('connected to peripheral: ' + peripheral.uuid);

    /*    find the right service (Cycling Speed and Cadence)    */
    peripheral.discoverServices(['1816'], function(error, services) {

      var CSCService = services[0];
      console.log('discovered CSC Service: ' + CSCService);

      /*    find the right characteristic (Cycling Speed and Cadence Measurement)    */
      CSCService.discoverCharacteristics(['2a5b'], function(error, characteristics) {

        var CSCMCharacteristic = characteristics[0];
        console.log('discovered CSC Measurement Characteristic: ' + CSCMCharacteristic);

        // problem is here: how to get cumulative wheel revolutions?
        CSCMCharacteristic.on('data', function(data, isNotification) {
          console.log('CSC Measurement is now: ', data.readUInt32LE(1));
        });

        // to enable notify
        CSCMCharacteristic.subscribe(function(error) {
          console.log('notification on');
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code was mostly right, except that the offset is 1, not 4 (code edited to reflect this). The funny numbers were being generated by a bug in the Tacx Vortex firmware. Firmware and offset updated, code now works.